# SQL query to find the max and min for each different day

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

```
id     value truncated_day just_yyyy_mm_dd
1167    300 7/1/11 0:00  7/1/11
1167    301 7/1/11 0:00 7/1/11
1167    303 7/1/11 0:00 7/1/11
1167    308 7/1/11 0:00 7/1/11
1167    312 7/2/11 0:00 7/2/11
1167    316 7/2/11 0:00 7/2/11
1167    318 7/2/11 0:00 7/2/11
1167    330 7/2/11 0:00 7/2/11
1700    0   7/1/11 0:00 7/1/11
1700    10  7/1/11 0:00 7/1/11
1700    21  7/1/11 0:00 7/1/11
1700    33  7/1/11 0:00 7/1/11
1700    34  7/2/11 0:00 7/2/11
1700    35  7/2/11 0:00 7/2/11
1700    40  7/2/11 0:00 7/2/11
```

The table is actually very long (more than 32 million rows!!).

I would like to have the max and min values (read_value) for each day, and for each different id. I tried the following query but it does not work:

```
'$'select id, 
date_trunc('day', timestamp_utc) as truncated_day, 
substring(cast(date_trunc('day', timestamp_utc) as text) from 1 for 10) as just_yyyy_mm_dd,
max(value) as maxvalue,
min(value) as minvalue
from TABLE
order by device_id, truncated_day'$'
```

I basically would like the query to return:

```
id    min    max truncated_day just_yyyy_mm_dd
1167    300 308 7/1/11 0:00 7/1/11
1167    312 330 7/2/11 0:00 7/2/11
1700    0   33  7/1/11 0:00 7/1/11
1700    34  40  7/2/11 0:00 7/2/11
```

Could you please help me with this query?
Thank you very much in advance!
N

Comment: sorry for the format:initial table:
d value truncated_day just_yyyy_mm_dd
1167 300 7/1/11 0:00 7/1/11
1167 301 7/1/11 0:00 7/1/11
1167 303 7/1/11 0:00 7/1/11
1167 308 7/1/11 0:00 7/1/11
1167 312 7/2/11 0:00 7/2/11
1167 316 7/2/11 0:00 7/2/11
1167 318 7/2/11 0:00 7/2/11
1167 330 7/2/11 0:00 7/2/11
1700 0 7/1/11 0:00 7/1/11
1700 10 7/1/11 0:00 7/1/11
1700 21 7/1/11 0:00 7/1/11
1700 33 7/1/11 0:00 7/1/11
1700 34 7/2/11 0:00 7/2/11
1700 35 7/2/11 0:00 7/2/11
1700 40 7/2/11 0:00 7/2/11

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.  Note addition of GROUP BY.  You can add the just_yyyy_mm_dd stuff back in if you need it.

```
select id, 
date_trunc('day', timestamp_utc) as truncated_day, 
max(value) as maxvalue,
min(value) as minvalue
from TABLE
GROUP BY id, date_trunc('day', timestamp_utc)
order by device_id, truncated_day
```

Comment: BTW, is this postgres?  It's good to specify what RDBMS you are using!

Comment: And for getting just_yyyy_mm_dd, you could try using something like to_char().  It'll make your life easier, I think.  See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-formatting.html

Comment: Yes it is postgres (sorry I forgot to specify it)

Answer (score 0):

You need a "group by", before the "order by". Basically you need to group by the first 3 fields.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `order by` to a `group by`.  Actually, you probably want both:

```
select device_id, date_trunc('day', timestamp_utc) as truncated_day, 
           substring(cast(date_trunc('day', timestamp_utc) as text) from 1 for 10) as just_yyyy_mm_dd,
           max(value) as maxvalue,
            min(value) as minvalue
from TABLE
group by device_id, date_trunc('day', timestamp_utc)
order by device_id, truncated_day
```

I am curious whether `group by device_id, truncated_day` would work.  Does the SQL compiler generate an error on the just_yyyy_mm_dd column?  It doesn't *need* to generate an error, but it might not recognize that expression as being only on the aggregation columns.

Comment: I will let you know if it work as soon as I get something, the query is still running. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, min(value) as 'minvalue', max(value) as 'maxvalue', truncated_day, just_yy_mm_dd
from the_table
group by truncated_day, id, just_yy_mm_dd
```